# When the size of object of firestoreConnect is more than 3 and includes "where" ,it occurs error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Is there another way to solve this problem.

When the size of object of firestoreConnect is more than 3 and includes "where" then it does not work and component goes blank.
Unless the screen is reloaded or transited, the fetch result is shown.

As far as I see the console, the size of projects array is 0.

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection : 'projects',
      limit :55,
      orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc'], 
      where:["tags", "array-contains-any", ["stack"]] ,
    }])
)(Dashboard);
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/feahktg87z0i11i/20221019_171555.mp4?dl=0

Comment: shinzo_abe, do let me know if the answer below was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of the [compose function](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) is important. You can try and use the firestoreConnect([...]) component to be the first parameter passed in, followed by connect(mapStateToProps).
It is now recommended to use Firestore hooks try useFirestoreConnect() from 'react-redux-firebase' and useSelector() from 'react-redux'.
You may have a look at this [Github link mentioning a similar implementation](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/846)
These are a few example links with helpful workarounds for the issue related to [mapstateprops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops?rq=1) and [firestore connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615159/firestoreconnect-doesnt-map-collection-to-state-in-react-redux-firebase).
Check the useful documentation for [Connect Mapstate](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)